# Timeout SqlException when using IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to write an integration test that tests my FluentNHibernate mapping configuration. The basic idea of the test is to insert some data, then read it back, and ensure the inserted data matches the data read back. I don't want to add test data into the database on every test run, so I attempt to insert the data using a transaction, and while that transaction is still open, I attempt to read the uncommitted data back (using a separate session). The plan is that once the assertions have been made, I will rollback the transaction around the inserting of data, leaving my database in the same state that it was in before the test ran. Unfortunately though, I'm getting the following error at the point of trying to read the data:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not load an entity: [CQRSTutorial.DAL.EventDescriptor#51ff4d15-ddbc-4157-8652-a7a10177a6e3][SQL: SELECT eventdescr0_.Id as Id1_2_0_, eventdescr0_.EventType as EventT2_2_0_, eventdescr0_.Data as Data3_2_0_ FROM Events eventdescr0_ WHERE eventdescr0_.Id=?]  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I've created a test specifically to highlight this issue, as follows:

```
[TestFixture, Category(TestConstants.Integration)]
public class TimeoutExpiredTest
{
    private ISession _writeSession;

    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Unspecified)
    {
        var msSqlConfiguration = MsSqlConfiguration
            .MsSql2012
            .IsolationLevel(isolationLevel)
            .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("CQRSTutorial"));

        var cfg = new CustomAutomappingConfiguration();
        return Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(msSqlConfiguration)
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.AutoMappings.Add(
                    AutoMap.AssemblyOf<EventDescriptor>(cfg)
                        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<EventDescriptorMapping>());
            })
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _writeSession = CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        _writeSession.BeginTransaction();
    }

    [Test]
    public void InsertAndReadTabOpened()
    {
        var objectToStoreInDbTemporarily = GetObjectToStoreInDbTemporarily();

        _writeSession.SaveOrUpdate(objectToStoreInDbTemporarily);
        _writeSession.Flush(); // the data needs to go to the database (even if only temporarily), rather than just staying in an NHibernate cache.

        var readSession = CreateSessionFactory(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).OpenSession();
        var retrievedEventDescriptor = readSession.Get<EventDescriptor>(objectToStoreInDbTemporarily.Id); // this line throws the exception after 30 seconds.

        // If previous line worked, I could then assert inserted values match retrieved values at this point.
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _writeSession.Transaction?.Rollback();
    }

    public class CustomAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
        {
            return type.Name == typeof(EventDescriptor).Name; // we're only mapping this class for now.
        }
    }
```

I've left out the code that creates the object for brevity. The original test served it's purpose - it forced to me to have to correctly define the NHibernate mapping for the object in question. But the original test was inserting new rows on every test run, which feels dirty and unnecessary - hence this transaction / rollback approach.

**Looking in SQL Profiler, it seems the problem is on the Read side - the Read session is using IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted rather than IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted. Any ideas why the read-session would not use the IsolationLevel specified in the test?**

Comment: Have you verified that your call to `BeginTransaction()` is definitely opening a transaction with the `ReadUncommitted` isolation level? Although it's specified when you create your config, I think it's still worth checking. In addition, have you tried querying in SQL Server with the `read uncommitted` isolation level to see if SQL Server behaves as expected?

Comment: Thanks for that, David. I've just checked in SQL Profiler, and I can see transaction opening for the write-sesson - that opens as ReadCommitted which is fine. However the read-session (that I've tried to configure as ReadUncommitted) is showing in the profiler as ReadCommitted - hence the timeout. Also, while debugging this test, I could see the uncommitted data in Sql Server Management Studio while using transaction isolation level ReadUncommitted. So the only thing to figure out now is *why* the read-session is opening as ReadCommitted instead of the specified ReadUncommitted.

Comment: Could you try and change this line, from the test setup: `_writeSession.BeginTransaction();` to `_writeSession.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);` and see what effect it has? It could be that setting the isolation level at the configuration level is not having the desired effect.

Comment: I've just tried that there now, David, just in case, but it doesn't work - I get the same issue - this makes sense to me, as the SQL Profiler indicates that the read-session is using the wrong isolation level, not the write-session. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I've just taken a second look and I'm wondering if it's because the `readSession.Get()` has no explicit transaction. Therefore, NH is using an implicit transaction with a read committed isolation level? Maybe wrap the `readSession.Get()` in an explicit transaction with read uncommitted isolation level?

Comment: Thanks David. This works:
`code`var readSession = CreateSessionFactory(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).OpenSession();
            using (var transaction = readSession.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                var retrievedEventDescriptor = readSession.Get<EventDescriptor>(objectToStoreInDbTemporarily.Id);
                Assert.That(retrievedEventDescriptor, Is.Not.Null);
            }
I'd rather not have to create this explicit transaction though - I'd like to understand why the CreateSessionFactory(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted) has no effect.

Comment: Good question. It's worth bearing in mind that explicit transactions are recommended: https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn#DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer, David, but I don't have the option to accept it. I think maybe it's because you've commented on the question rather than posting an "answer". If you want to re-post the answer around using the explicit transaction, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Ronan Moriarty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've just taken a second look and I'm wondering if it's because the `readSession.Get()` has no explicit transaction. Therefore, NH is using an implicit transaction with a read committed isolation level? Maybe wrap the `readSession.Get()` in an explicit transaction with read uncommitted isolation level?

Answer (score 0):

As said by David Osborne, you need to open a transaction for your read session too.

But what you are doing is quite debatable. Your are relying on internal implementation details of the SQL server for your test to succeed. The fact it currently works will not be guaranteed.

Better implement proper tests setup and teardown, doing the required cleanup. Your tests will be far more reliable.

Another solution could be to share the connection between your two sessions, either by supplying it when opening the sessions, or by spawning one session from the other. This way their entity cache will not be shared but they will be able to read each other data without it being committed, since they will be in the same transaction.

And yet another solution is to use a single transaction scope to do your test, removing the NHibernate transactions. Both session would be in the same transaction and will be able to read each other data. But this may promote the transaction to distributed, and your setup will then need to support it. (MSDTC would need to be enabled on the testing host.)

Comment: Thanks Frédéric - yes, sharing connection between sessions sounds like another viable way to solve this. I wanted to keep this as lightweight as possible so am avoiding MSDTC (haven't used MSDTC before though so unsure of what's involved there)

I don't understand how I'm relying on internal SQL server implementation details though - could you clarify? Also, I was trying to find a solution that would require minimum specific setup / teardown for each and every future integration tests - I wanted to devise a generic solution that could be leveraged by all future tests with minimum effort.